# got rid of "others" but now I have more syncing problems

Tags: iphone, itunes

A message appears stating that an error occurred while syncing, with the error number "(-54)". Then it says that I do not have "access privileges" to sync my iPhone and complete the process. All my contacts have been completely deleted. iTunes is not allowing me to restore my phone to a backup before installing iOS5 update.

Answer (score 2):

The -54 error is defined as follows : `Software lock on file; Not a subscriber`

Is your computer Authorized ? iTunes -> Store -> Authorize this computer ?

Otherwise you don't have the correct permissions to a file you are trying to use for the sync. Try running the following script to see if it helps. It will unlock all files in your `~/Music` folder.

```
tell application "Finder"
set locked of every item of entire contents of folder "Music:iTunes" of home to false
end tell
```

Reference [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1124429?threadID=1124429&tstart=0)